# Percentile_rank calculation as filter for count calculations

Tags: tableau-api, rank, percentile

Current status -  Percentile_rank filter works with dimension as per following image,
[image]

Now I would like to filter number of hospitals in range of 50 - 80%  - Expected count will **4** hospitals. But Rank_percentile filter not showing / working correctly

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a measure using different:

IF variable > 0.5 and variable < 0.8 THEN "50-80%"
ELSE variable > 0.8 and variable < 1 THEN "80-100%"
END

Then use the measure as a filter or as any other measure and voilà.

If you have any doubts, try guiding yourself using this link: https://community.tableau.com/thread/254997

Regards,

IC